# Como se podria condicionar un combobox?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Me explico, tengo este combobox, al seleccionar uno de sus values: current(0) salte esas lineas, current(1) las lea.

Estoy probando pero siempre se cumple el ELSE.

```
if self.mycombo_factura_titulo == 1:
                instancia = Rango_RNC(self.inicio, self.final)
                self.datos = instancia.datos
            else:
                print(0)

if self.mycombo_factura_titulo['values'] == ['FACTURA CREDITO FISCAL']:
                
                instancia = Rango_RNC(self.inicio, self.final)
                self.datos = instancia.datos
            else : 
                print("0")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la línea 42 tienes que cambiar el segundo parámetro por `True`.

Comment: asi @CandidMoe? if self.mycombo_factura_titulo.current(0):
                self.numero_RNC() == False
            else:
                True

Answer (score 0):

se evaluaba con el .GET()

```
if self.mycombo_factura_titulo.get() == 'FACTURA CREDITO FISCAL':
                
                instancia = Rango_RNC(self.inicio, self.final)
                self.datos = instancia.datos
```